# c++ set and shared_ptr

Tags: c++, set, shared-ptr

I have class X like:

```
class X {
    public:
        bool operator<(const SCN& other) const;
};
```

Then I have the following code:

```
std::multiset<std::shared_ptr<X>> m;
```

My questions are:

1. how the data in m is ordered?   the address of `X(shared_ptr)` or the `X.operator<`? If it is ordered by address of `X`, how can I make it order by `X.operator<`?
2. for this `m`,  if I want to access its elements from smallest to biggest, can the following code guarantee that? If not, How?

   ```
   for (auto& i : m) {
       f(i);
   }
   ```

Comment: 1.) The set will be ordered by the pointers the shared_ptr(s) hold. 2.) It will iterate from low to high (but in terms of 1.)

Comment: that's really make sense for my current situation.  what is the best way to order by the X.operator< ?

Comment: Actually I have read [shared_ptr relation operator](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/shared_ptr/operators/)and [owner_less](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/memory/owner_less/)before I ask this question here.  but I still not sure about this.   to implement my idea, Can I just define m as std::multiset<std::shared_ptr<X>, owner_less(std::shared_ptr<X>)> ?

Comment: You can use: std::multiset with your own compare functor: `struct Less { bool operator () (std::shared_ptr<X> a, std::shared_ptr<X> b) { return ... } };`. But be warned: std::shared_ptr breaks const correctness logically!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your set is ordered based on your key_type which is `std::shared_ptr<X>`. As your `std::shared_ptr<X>` is [comparable](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/operator_cmp), the ordering of the [std::shared_ptr](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) prevails.

For the sake of reference, multiset is defined as

```
template<
    class Key,
    class Compare = std::less<Key>,
    class Allocator = std::allocator<Key>
> class multiset;
```

As can be seen, `typename Compare` is `std::less<Key>` and [std::less](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/less) should overload the function overload which would possibly be implemented as

```
constexpr bool operator()(const T &lhs, const T &rhs) const 
{
    return lhs < rhs;
}
```

both `lhs` and `rhs` is of type `T` which in this case is `Key` which is the type that we have instantiated multiset with which is `std::shared_ptr<X>`.